# mysql query giving data but skipping empty values

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which gives the results but not as expected

```
select g.id
     , g.name
     , COUNT(p1.id) as total 
  from ft_smsender_groups as g
     , ft_smsender_persons as p1
     ,ft_smsender_persons2groups as p2 
 where g.id = p2.group_id 
   and p1.id = p2.person_id 
 group 
    by id
     , name
```

This gives me the values of groups with each person associated to them,

but it is skipping those groups which do not have any person associated,

i need to modify this query to give me all group names so i no person is assigned, it should give that `total` column value as `0`

Comment: Rewrite using proper join syntax, then get back to us

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

```
select g.id,g.name, count(p2.id) as total from ft_smsender_
groups as g left join (select p1.id,p2.group_id 
from ft_smsender_persons2groups as p2  inner join ft_smsender_persons 
as p1 on p1.id = p2.person_id ) as p2 on g.id = p2.group_id group by id,name
```

Comment: gives me an error: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p1.id = p2.person_id 
group by id,name' at line 4

Comment: still it is not sowing me the groups with no person assigned to them

Comment: fixed, u need left join on both

Comment: check it. Its also give Correct Answer